# RSA encryption in Java, decrypt in PHP

Tags: java, php, encryption, rsa

Assume I have the following Java code to generate a Public-private keypair:

```
KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance ("RSA");
SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");

generator.initialize (1024, random);

KeyPair pair = generator.generateKeyPair();
RSAPrivateKey priv = (RSAPrivateKey)pair.getPrivate();
RSAPublicKey pub = (RSAPublicKey)pair.getPublic();

// Sign a message
Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
dsa.initSign (priv);
dsa.update ("Hello, World".getBytes(), 0, "Hello, World".length());

byte[] out = dsa.sign();
/* save the signature in a file */
FileOutputStream sigfos = new FileOutputStream("sig");
sigfos.write(out);
sigfos.close();
```

How would one go about and decrypt the file "sig" in PHP? I've read the post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1662887/414414 which supplies a function to convert a `DER` file to `PEM` (Assume I also save the public key from Java).

I have tried something like:

```
$key = openssl_pkey_get_public ("file://pub_key.pem");
$data = null;
openssl_public_decrypt ( file_get_contents ("sig"), $data, $key);
echo $data, "\n";
```

It successfully decrypts the message, but it is many weird characters.

Our scenario is a Java client that is sending messages to a PHP server, but encrypts the data with a private key. PHP knows about the public key, which it should use to decrypt and validate the message.

I've read a lot of posts regarding this issue here on SO, but I've come to realize that this is a bit specific issue, especially if there's different algorithms in use, etc. So sorry if this may be a duplicate.

Any feedbacks are greatly appreciated!

Comment: "It successfully decrypts the message, but it is many weird characters." - can you be more specific about that? Could it simply be an encoding issue?

Comment: Does the decoded message sort of look like the original text, or is it completely garbled?

Comment: are you trying to verify messages sent between Java and PHP, or encrypt them? or both?

Comment: Can you post a sample key and some cipher text corresponding to that key so that we might test it out ourselves? Thanks!

Comment: The resulted data looked something like: `0!0     ♠♣+♫♥☻→♣ ♦¶öúò╝├üi»j¾∟ƒpQ§Ç↔XVè`. So it would seem that it isn't an encoding issue.

Comment: I think I got the same question you've faced....but openssl_verify() doesn't work for me ....[Question Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370046/use-php-openssl-verify-function-to-verify-signature-and-data-created-by-androi) Please help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

an "RSA signature" is usually more than just "encrypt with private key, decrypt with public key", since Public key protocols like PKCS#1 also specify padding schemes, and all signature schemes will encrypt a digest of the message, instead of the full message.  I cannot find any documentation if java's signature scheme uses the signature padding scheme specified in PKCS#1, but my suspicion is that it is.

If it is, you will instead want to use the `openssl_verify` method in PHP, documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-verify.php).  This will return a 0 or 1 if the signature is invalid or valid, respectively.

In the event that Java does not use a padding scheme, your issue is that the data encrypted in the signature is a hash of the message, instead of the message itself (you can see in the Java code that it uses the SHA-1 hash algorithm).  So on the PHP side, you will need to take the sha1 hash of your message using the [sha1 method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) with `$raw_output` set to true, and compare those strings to ensure your message is valid.

Comment: Thank you so much! Since the signature is going to be based upon various HTTP headers and its values, I can put this together on the server side and check if the signature is valid: `openssl_verify ("Hello, World", file_get_contents ('sig'), $pubkey)`. And that works ;-)

Comment: I think I got the same question....but openssl_verify() doesn't work for me ....[Question link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370046/use-php-openssl-verify-function-to-verify-signature-and-data-created-by-androi) Please help, thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

From the snippet

```
$key = openssl_pkey_get_public ("file://pub_key.pem");
```

It looks like you're referencing the public key, which would be the wrong one to decrypt. Double check ?

Comment: It's signature verification, so using the public key seems correct to me.

Comment: Is a signature verification, yes, so the server should never know the private key..